# PHP dynamically added square bracket inputs not passing via POST

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, post

I have problem with dynamically added inputs. They're not passing via `POST`. I get only one input group which is static. I am using Codeigniter.

Here is code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <?php echo form_input('product[]', '', 'class="Value form-control product" placeholder="Produkt" id="product"');?>  
</div>      
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <?php echo form_input('product_id[]', '', 'class="Value form-control" placeholder="ID" id="product_id" readonly') ?>    <br>
</div>      

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <?php echo form_input('price[]', '', 'class="Value form-control" placeholder="Cena" id="product"');?>   
</div>      
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <?php echo form_input('qtty[]', '', 'class="Value form-control" placeholder="Ilość" id="product_id"') ?>    
</div>  
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <?php echo form_input('sum[]', '', 'class="Value form-control" placeholder="Suma" id="product_id" readonly') ?> 
</div>
```

and my jQuery add function:

```
$("#addproduct").click(function() {

    var newtr = "<div class='col-sm-12 well'><div class='col-sm-10'><input type='text' name='product[]' value='' class='Value form-control product' placeholder='Produkt' id='product'></div><div class='col-sm-2'><input type='text' name='product_id[]' value='' class='Value form-control' placeholder='ID' id='product_id' readonly><br></div><div class='col-sm-4'><input type='text' name='price[]' value='' class='Value form-control' placeholder='Cena' id='product'></div><div class='col-sm-4'><input type='text' name='qtty[]' value='' class='Value form-control' placeholder='Ilość' id='product_id'></div><div class='col-sm-4'><input type='text' name='sum[]' value='' class='Value form-control' placeholder='Suma' id='product_id' readonly></div></div><br><br>";

    $("#products_container").append(newtr);
    $("#products_container").find('.product').last().autocomplete(options).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.price + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };  
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure when u append the new input, it is inside the form tags ?

Comment: I don't _think_ it's related to your problem, but you're using the same id for multiple elements, which is not good.

Comment: Yes, they're in the same place like first static. I tried also few static inputs with food[] name and it worked.

Comment: Can you create fiddle with an example form? then maybe we could help :)

Comment: It would help to see the rendered HTML.

Comment: Nevermid... unclosed div tag ruined my two hours... Thanks for help.